# Use nullptr instead of end iterator

Tags: c++, stl

I would like to know if it is possible to use nullptr or some kind of generic end iterator.

For example:

```
// a.b->cdef().g->bdf() is a std::map<int, int>
std::unordered_map<int, int> copy(a.b->cdef().g->bdf().begin(), a.b->cdef().g->bdf().end());
```

is what you would normally write to specify the begin and end to initialize the new map.

Why do I need to specify the end tag if I just want to copy the whole map.

I would prefer something like:

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> copy(a.b->cdef().g->bdf().begin(), nullptr);
```

or

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> copy(a.b->cdef().g->bdf().begin());
```

or

```
std::unordered_map<int, int> copy(a.b->cdef().g->bdf().begin(), std::unordered_map::end);
```

**edit**: I changed the example from a std::list<int> to a std::unordered_map<int, int>. There is no copy constructor from std::map to std::unordered_map.

Comment: Do the three statements you wrote work? What does your compiler say?

Comment: `std::list<int> copy(a.b->cdef().g->bdf());`

Comment: No they don't work. I would like to know if there is something in STL that works similarly so I don't have to specify the end() iterator.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list constructor #4 takes 2 iterators as input and copies the elements. This is what I would like to do.
I added a.b->cdef().g->bdf() as an example of a long argument I do not want to repeat.

Comment: Ok, maybe the list is a bad example. My initial goal was to copy the elements of a std::map<std::string, std::string> to a std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> which cannot simply be done via a copy constructor or assignment operator. Thought it would be easier to have the std::list as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer the question asked, "Is it possible to use nullptr instead of end()?"

No.

Please think about how the containers and iterators are implemented. A container knows its begin and end iterators. An iterator knows how to increment, decrement and compare itself to another iterator.

So take a vector for example. How does the begin iterator know where to stop incrementing? How would `iter == nullptr` know when to return true so it could stop?

Or take a circular linked list. It has no real end. It only stops when an iterator equals the begin iterator again. What would nullptr even mean as an end there?

If you think about the implementation you'll see why the answer is "No."

Comment: I accepted this answer as it answers my question whether it is possible. And the answer is no. It also includes a reason why.
The vector is what helped me get that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy the contents of a whole container into a container of a different type you can use a helper function

```
template<typename InputIterRange, typename OutputIter>
OutputIter range_copy(InputIterRange&& range, OutputIter out_iter)
{
  return std::copy(range.begin(), range.end(), out_iter);
}
```

This works as long as the `value_type`s of each container are convertible to each other. Example use:

```
int main() {
    std::set<int> a{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::unordered_set<int> b {11,22,33};
    range_copy(a, std::inserter(b, b.end()));
}
```

Comment: For std::copy you need 2 iterators as well.

Comment: @Bantak Added an example.

Comment: The whole point of my question is to reduce size and not have to pass 2 iterators, but 1.

Comment: @Bantak Only one iterator is being passed here.

Answer (score 1):

Copying of ranges in the STL is mostly specified using a pair of iterators.   This is because most copying operations need to be finite, and it is hard to specify a finite range using a single iterator.

`nullptr` is not an iterator that any standard container will return, and does not provide an alternative.

Alternatives include adding a helper function that accepts containers as arguments (preferably by reference).  Then it is possible to extract iterators from those containers with less fuss.

The best option is almost certainly to improve your basic design and coding technique to avoid the need for code to explicitly dig down through an excessive number of nested structs to find data (e.g. `a.b->cdef().g->bdf()`).   Simple and readable code is easier to understand and therefore easier to get right.