# Why c++ std::find return container.end() instead of NULL to signify "not found"?

Tags: c++

It always puzzle me whenever I have to type/read the verbose `if(it==some_container.end()){...}` like:

```
auto it=std::find(some_container.begin(),some_container.end());
if(it==some_container.end()){...}
...
```

It seems returning NULL is perfectly valid and returning `end()` provides no benefits.

Some other languages also simply return their equivalent of NULL/null_ptr in similar situations, and works perfectly well.

Comment: `NULL` is an old C compatibility macro for null *pointers*. Neither C nor C++ have any kind of "null" values.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. `.end()` signifies the end of a range, not that something is "not found". The idiom that you're describing is used when searching if a container contains a value for example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938457/use-nullptr-instead-of-end-iterator

Comment: @tenfour: I agree, this one is a valid question. I downvote only questions that ask us to do their homework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use nullptr instead of end iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938457/use-nullptr-instead-of-end-iterator)

Answer (score 1):

By way of a counter example, it is, in many guises, possible to decrement the `end()` iterator with

```
--end()
```

in order to recover the final element in the container. In various containers `end()` is set to one beyond the final element.

If `end()` was `NULL` then `NULL` would have to contain embedded type information in order for the above to be possible. For the generic `NULL` that isn't.

tl;dr, `NULL` has no type information, but `end()` does.

Comment: The question doesn't seem to be "why isn't end() NULL", but rather "why isn't NULL used to represent not-found instead of end".

Answer (score 1):

The decision to return the iterator to what you are looking for seems like the correct one to me. However, that means that when you haven't found the element, you still have to return something or throw an exception.

You can't return NULL or nullptr because they are not iterators. Throwing an exception seem like overkill, because finding something includes the possibility of the element being not present and especially when a loop, the exception could become costly. std::optional looks like the best option to me but it wasn't available at the time. container.end() is an iterator and doesn't point to any element in the container, so it is usable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that was a design decision of the STL designers.

And for all we know, end() might even *be* NULL or null_ptr. It is an implementation detail that we don't want to know about.

Comment: But still, the question is valid. std::optional has an implicit bool operator, and I really miss that for iterators. With it, one could write ```if (iter)``` instead of ```if (iter == mycontainer.end())```, making the intent of the code much clearer.

Comment: @cptFracassa: I also miss a lot of things in the STL, like more standardized methods to access containers so I can change the container type easier. And using the unsigned size_t for the container size was also a mistake...

Comment: 'size_t' for container size is not enforced by the standard though.

Comment: `end()` can only be `nullptr` for forward iterators. For bidirectional iterators, you can go back, which requires a unique per-container `end()`.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer: Well, .size() returns a size_t, that makes using an int e.g. a bug. Fortunately the new loop constructs make iterators unneccessary so they should not be used manually anymore.

Comment: @U.W. Nope, `Container<T>::size()` returns `Container<T>::size_type` which may be `size_t` but is not guaranteed. Of course using an `int` for element count is wrong if `size_type` > `int`.

Comment: @NotAProgrammer: After all these years I can still learn something new about C++ almost every day... Even using auto is not foolproof, because then you can get an unsigned type which can make calculations (like `x < 0`)tricky...

Answer (score 0):

On the contrary, using "NULL" provides no benefits. All ranges have an end. But not all iterator types necessarily have a representation for "NULL". Using "NULL" to represent "not found" would limit using such function only with iterators that are nullable. This is an unnecessary limitation since end iterator can be used instead. The chosen design is the one that doesn't have the limitation.

---

Consider using pointer as an iterator. Typical loop goes like this:

```
T* end = find(...);
for(T* it = container.begin(); it != end; it++)
```

If `find()` returns "NULL", then this loop wouldn't work. You'd need to add extra checks that are unnecessary now:

```
if (!end)
    end = container.end();
```

Comment: It can, when the ++ operator turns `it` into NULL...

Comment: @U.W. That can in theory work with at most one array in the entire program.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm is iterator based, so the return value should be a valid iterator

Answer (score 0):

I agree with all who are saying that functions should return a valid iterator, as they do now.

But the current solution *is* bad. Iterators forces us to use a syntax where you must compare the iterator to someContainer.end(), when what you want semantically, is to check that the iterator is valid.

I wish iterators could be redesigned, inspired by std::optional to have a hidden bool, which all algorithms set to true when returning a valid iterator, and false if not - and similarily to std::optional had a `bool has_value() const` method, and also like std::optional operator bool for this.

That way you could write code like this:

```
auto iter = find(myContainer.begin(), myContainer.end(), 7);
if (iter) // or (iter.has_value()) or (iter != myContainer.end())
{
 ...
}
```

This make the syntax express the intent, unlike how it is now. This would not break existing code, though I guess Therese would be sone problems implementing this...